# Is it possible to enable/disable certain Snakemake rules using command line flags

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to have the snakemake file and/or the rules files configured to execute certain rules only in certain cases using command line switches.

To elaborate, lets say I have these rules in my rules folder:

- rule 1
- rule 2a
- rule 2b
- rule 2c
- rule 3

Is it possible to configure/execute the workflow in this way:

- call `snakemake --user_option 2a` will cause  rule 1, rule 2a,
  rule 3 to be invoked
- call `snakemake --user_option 2b` will cause  rule 1, rule 2b, rule 3 to be invoked
- and so on

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass the `user_option` as a configuration key at the command line and then have an `if-else` that decides what intermediate rule to use. E.g.

```
snakemake --config option='2a'
```

The dummy Snakefile:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'output.txt',

rule one:
    output:
        'foo.txt'

if config['option'] == '2a':
    rule two_a:
        input:
            'foo.txt',
        output:
            'bar.txt',
elif config['option'] == '2b':
    rule two_b:
        input:
            'foo.txt',
        output:
            'bar.txt',
else:
    sys.exit() ## handle this case

rule three:
    input:
        'bar.txt',
    output:
        'output.txt',
```